# Hockeyapp for Xamarin.mac application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac, hockeyapp

I have wrote binding library for mac osx, (using HockeySDK.framework). Here is how my ApiDefinition.cs is looks like :

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    interface BITHockeyManager
    {
        [Static, Export ("sharedHockeyManager")]
        BITHockeyManager SharedHockeyManager { get; }
        [Export ("crashManager")]
        BITCrashManager CrashManager { get; }
        [Export ("configureWithIdentifier:")]
        void ConfigureWithIdentifier (NSString appIdentifier);
        [Export ("startManager")]
        void StartManager ();
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    interface BITCrashManager
    {
        [Export ("setAutoSubmitCrashReport:")]
        void SetAutoSubmitCrashReport (bool flag);
    }
```

Also here is the calling part (AppDelegate.cs) :

```
public override void DidFinishLaunching (NSNotification notification)
        {
            HockeyAppLib.BITHockeyManager manager = HockeyAppLib.BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
            manager.ConfigureWithIdentifier (new NSString (AppIdentifier));
            manager.CrashManager.SetAutoSubmitCrashReport (true);
            manager.StartManager ();
        }
```

Is seems , that everything is o, but I can't get crash reports in the server. Any idea?

Comment: The initial installation of your app has to be done over HockeyApp in order to successfully register the device. Did you do that?

Comment: @greenhoorn That is not true, the HockeyApp SDK should work no matter how the app is installed.

Comment: @Nininea Could you try adding bindings for the debug log switch too and see if that outputs anything useful? https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Mac#debug

Comment: thanks for answers, I was throwing new exception and hockeyapp didn't log this error. Now I changed nullpointreference exception, and it wokrs now. But I can't get readable stacktrace, any options?